# integral, bijection

Tags: integration

Is there a way to compute the intergral of a bijection by using its symetry?

Meaning is there a way to proove ( maybe by a substitution) that

$$\int_0^2 e^x dx = \int_1^{l} \ln(x)dx$$

(i m not sur about the bounds of the integral... that's why i ve written $l$, I can't find the upper bound)

and then to generalize this idea for any bijection. Especially I was thinking about $ \frac{1}{x} $ which we can't compute the integral on $\mathbb{R}^+$ but nevertheless we have :

$$\int_0^1  \frac{1}{x} dx = \int_1^{\infty}  \frac{1}{x} dx$$

thank you :)

Comment: If you draw a graph it is fairly obvious that $\int_0^2e^x\ dx=2e^2-\int_1^{e^2}\log x\ dx$. Yes, your $1/x$ case is also fairly clear, but then both integrals are infinite, so you need to state the position rather more carefully.

Comment: it's clear by the symetry but I'm searching a justification within integrals

Comment: Integrate by parts:
$$\int_0^2 e^x dx=[xe^x]_0^2-\int_0^2 xe^x~dx$$
Substitute $x=\ln(u)$ on the integral of the RHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the following result is what you are after.

If $f$ is a bijective function with continuous derivative on the interval $[a,b]$, then
$$\int_a^b f(x) \, dx + \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1} (x) \, dx = b f(b) - a f(a).\tag1$$
Here $f^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of $f$.

For the case of your first example, setting $f(x) = \ln x$ with $a = 1, b = e^2$, as $f^{-1} (x) = e^x$ application of (1) gives
$$\int_1^{e^2} \ln x \, dx + \int_0^2 e^x \, dx = e^2 \cdot \ln (e^2) - 1 \cdot \ln (1),$$
or
$$\int_1^{e^2} \ln x \, dx = 2e^2 - \int_0^2 e^x \, dx.$$